# Converting a list of integers to a map of vertices containing the elements coordinates

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, sudoku

This is what i have at the moment

```
(string -> int list)
let read filename = ....
```

this is working as intended, returning a list of integers from a textfile looking like this:

```
530070000
600195000
098000060
800600003
400803001
700020006
060000280
000419005
000080079
```

Yes you are correct, it is a sudoku board. This is what i have to work with:

```
     type vertex = int * int (*Cells in the sudoku board*)
     type gamma = int (*representing colors 1-9*)
    
    (* [Vertex = Map.Make(Vertex)] *)
    
             module Vertex = Map.Make(struct 
                 type t = vertex
                 let compare = Stdlib.compare
                 end) 

     (* [Gamma = Set.Make(Gamma)] *)
             module Gamma = Set.Make(struct
                 type t = gamma
                 let compare = Stdlib.compare
                 end)
```

The gamma set is for solving the sudoku board using graph coloring. I need help understanding how i can convert the list of integers to a suitable map for this kind of task. According to the structure i provided, so i can access each element in the map using it coordinates (x, y). Hope you understand, otherwise i will try to provide more info. I'm reaaally bad at OCaml but trying to learn. I'm sorry for body errors etc, first time posting here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your task, the text file contains a grid of digits with the initial disposition for sudoku. So you shouldn't interpret a line in the file as a single integer but rather as a list of integers. You can either change your `read` function so that it returns `int list list` instead of `int list` and then use `List.fold_left` over the list that will also count the position of an element in the list, but it is tedious. It is much easier to read the grid directly from the file, e.g.,

```
let read_matrix chan =
  let rec loop i j grid =
    match input_char chan with
    | exception End_of_file -> grid
    | '\n' -> loop (i+1) 0 grid
    | '0'..'9' as c ->
      loop i (j+1) @@
      Vertex.add (i,j) (ascii_digit c) grid
    | _ -> invalid_arg "invalid input" in
  loop 0 0 Vertex.empty
```

where `ascii_digit` is defined as,

```
let ascii_digit c = Char.code c - Char.code '0'
```

The `read_matrix` function takes the channel as input so to read the grid from a file you can define,

```
let matrix_from_file file =
  let chan = open_in file in
  let r = read_matrix chan in
  close_in chan;
  r
```

Hint: you probably also don't want to include positions with `0` in your grid. It is easy to achieve, just add another case to the pattern in the `loop` function that will skip it, e.g.,

```
...
| '0' -> loop i (j+1) grid
...
```

Comment: This might be a weird question but how can i recursiveley iterate over the map and replace ”zeros” with values 1-9? Without breaking the rules of sudoku? Any ideas/tip? 